# Angular 4 and Prerender.io Integration

Tags: angular, prerender

I am trying to use prerender.io for my angular 4 application but i am not able to render my html pages

I followed this https://github.com/prerender/prerender/tree/chrome abd angular.io/guide/quickstart for prerender and angular 4 respectively

I have set up both things on my local
Then through cmd i ran the two applications separately on different ports localhost:3000 for prerender and /localhost:4200 for angular

And then i used this url http://localhost:3000/http://localhost:4200 
to render the page but it does not seem to load at all

Is prerender.io compatible with Angular 2 and Angular 4 or only with AngularJs?

Comment: You can ask this question to prerender support, also you should provide if there are any errors, either on browser-console-etc

Comment: Yeah please send us an email at support@prerender.io! I think we handled this issue and it was due to images not being loaded by our Prerender server by default, and your website was expecting images to load before inserting your HTML onto the page.